# Diferencia en crear arreglo de clases en c++

Tags: c++

Hola quisiera saber cual es la diferencia entre estos arreglos de clases o talvez están mal declaradas

Por ejemplo y en la primera declaracion quisiera saber como se destruye con con el delete tengo una clase llamada Ccuadrado y declaradas de las siguientes formas

```
    CCuadrado**aux = new CCuadrado*[6]
    CCuadrado *aux = new CCuadrado[6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Para eliminar la memoria reservada, en cada caso es distinto.

Para el caso de puntero simple:

```
CCuadrado* aux = new CCuadrado[6];
```

Al estar reservando memoria para 6 objetos de la clase `CCuadrado`, tienes que liberarlos como liberas cualquier array dinámico:

```
delete[] aux;
```

De esa forma eliminas el array completo y se llamará al destructor de cada objeto.

Par el segundo caso del doble puntero, cuando defines esto:

```
CCuadrado ** aux = new CCuadrado*[6];
```

Como ya te han dicho en otra respuesta, lo que reservas es un array de 6 punteros a objetos de la clase `CCuadrado`. Pero esos objetos aun no los tienes creados ni definidos. Solo has creado un array de punteros. Y como todo array se libera igual:

```
delete[] aux;
```

Pero esto te supone un problema porque en algún momento habrás reservado memoria para los objetos a los que apuntan los punteros. Habrás hecho algo como esto:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    aux[i] = new CCuadrado(....);
}
```

Así habrás creado los 6 objetos `CCuadrado` y habrás guardado sus direcciones de memoria en el array `aux` (doble puntero). Y estos objetos también hay que liberarlos, uno a uno, de la misma manera que los creaste, y antes de liberar el array reservado para los 6 punteros. Tendrías que hacer algo así otra vez:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    delete aux[i];
}
```

En este caso, en cada iteración llamará al destructor de cada objeto y liberará la memoria reservada. Y ya después podrás eliminar el array de punteros como te dije:

```
delete[] aux;
```

En definitiva. Tienes que ejecutar tantos `delete` como `new` hayas ejecutado. Y siempre tienes que tener en cuenta que si el `new` lo hiciste como array `new[]`, el `delete` tiene que ser del array `delete[]`. Sino, solo elimina el primer elemento del array.